# URL masking in .htaccess on a subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mask

found a few topics here, but they don't always answer exactly what I want or I don't understand how exactly the answer is meant by the author.

I have a domain exmaple.com and a subdomain app.example.com. I need the path exmaple.com/app to mask content from said subdomain.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^exmaple.com/s/
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://app.example.com/ [P]
```

Can you advise me how to achieve this effectively in htaccess?

Comment: Your RewriteCond there will never match - `exmaple.com/s/` is not a host name.

Comment: Does the subdomain point to a different server? What is `/s/`? What URL requests are you expecting, just `example.com/app` only?